# App Is Not Getting Signed - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, signing

when i am doing Build > Generate Signed APK, its showing Successful.

but when i try to install the app in my phone its showing install blocked (unknown Source)

this is what i got from jarsigner: http://prntscr.com/6ol50t

this is my build.gradle : http://prntscr.com/6ol5au

trying to find the solution from google from last 5 days, but not getting solution..

does i am missing something ?? :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off app verification

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2812853?hl=en

Comment: you know why i am trying to sign my application ?? i think no..

i am trying to sign my application so that anyone can install it without changing the settings > unknown Source..